# Preparation of Ca/PO4/acetate solution

Tags: stoichiometry, buffer

EDIT: This is not a homework problem and we need this for an exploratory study on teeth demineralization. There is further work planned around this activity, which may not be relevant to the question.

For this purpose, few publications have quoted the use of Ca/PO4/acetate solution containing 2mmol/L calcium, 2 mmol/L phosphate and 0.075 mol/L acetate at pH 4.5. This composition will supposedly emulate tooth demineralization environment closely.

We are a team of computer and electrical engineers with rusty basic (school level) chemistry skills. We tried to prepare few equations considering commercially easily available compounds e.g. calcium phosphate, calcium acetate, calcium oxide etc. But, we could not derive any balanced combination that could result in mentioned desired concentrations.

We avoided the use of elemental calcium, primarily because we wanted to avoid handling of such reactive element as it may further necessitate special lab equipment. But, if this is the only way to go, then please let us know.

So, can anybody help us with the method to prepare such a solution, if possible using compounds/mixtures available commonly in the market?

Acknowledging that this can very well be an artefact of our rusty and limited chemistry knowledge, so we are welcoming hints/pointers/keywords/references as well.

Appreciate your time and attention to our request.

Comment: So you want to prepare a solution containing 2 mmol/L calcium, 2 mmol/L phosphate and 0.075 mol/L acetate at pH 4.5. It is not an easy problem. You may dissolve 2 mmol CaCl2 (0.111 g), 2 mol NaH2PO4 (=0.283 g), and 0.075 mol acetic acid ( 4.5 g). If the pH is not 4.5, it may be adapted by adding some drops of NaOH 0.1 M ou HCl 0.1 M.  But take care of the fact that instead of getting anhydrous compounds CaCl2, NaH2PO4, you may get hydrated powders, like CaCl2·6H2O, or NaH2PO4·2H2O. In that case the masses have to be increased to take care of the number of water molecules..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to prepare a solution containing 2 mmol/L calcium, 2 mmol/L phosphate and 0.075 mol/L acetate at pH 4.5. It is not an easy problem. You may dissolve 2 mmol CaCl2 (0.111 g), 2 mmol NaH2PO4 (=0.283 g), and 0.075 mol acetic acid ( 4.5 g). If the pH is not 4.5, it may be adapted by adding one or two drops of NaOH 0.1 M ou HCl 0.1 M.

But take care of the fact that instead of getting anhydrous compounds CaCl2, NaH2PO4, you may only obtain bottles of hydrated powders, like CaCl2·6H2O, or NaH2PO4·2H2O. Anhydrous substances are not always easy to get. In that case the masses have to be increased to take care of the number of water molecules. The molar masses of the different hydrates are : 178 for Na2HPO4·2 H2O, 268 for   Na2HPO4·7H2O, 358 for Na2HPO4·12H2O, 147 for CaCl2·2H2O, and 219 for CaCl2·6H2O.

Comment: Thanks Maurice for your prompt, detailed and very helpful response. Your response definitely provides lot of clarity on the problem and a possible solution.
Fortunately, I can see that mentioned anhydrous compounds are available for sale on websites of local suppliers. 
We will give this a try and update how it goes.